# How can I tell if a search was successful in vimscript?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to learn vimscript.  I've read quite a bit in 'learn vimscript the hard way", but don't find the answers to my questions:

How can I tell if a search was successful in vimscript?  I hve two cases:

```
:if there's a ( on the current line
        do foo
:endif


:if /searchtarget succeeds
    do bar
:endif
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various approaches, depending on the context.

> :if there's a ( on the current line do foo :endif

You could use `search()`, as per @Kent's answer. It supports `{stopline}` argument, to avoid that it goes beyond the current line (which you can pass via `line('.')`). But it only searches in one direction (either forward or backward), so you'd have to position the cursor.

So it sounds like `if getline('.') =~ '('` is a better test. It does a regular expression comparison of the current line with `(`. You could also use `match()` instead (look up any function via `:help` for the full API documentation and examples BTW), or a non-regexp `stridx()` (which might be faster, but also is less clear to read).

> :if /searchtarget succeeds do bar :endif

Again, this sounds like a use for `search()`, which repositions the cursor on a match like `/search`. But you could also use the latter (with `:normal`), and check for a jump by comparing the cursor positions (obtained via `getpos('.')`) before and after the command.

Comment: One caveat about checking if the cursor position has changed after searching with `:normal /<pattern>`:  If there is only one match in the file, and it happens to be at the cursor position at the start of the search, then the search will wrap past the end of the file (assuming that option is on) and land at the current cursor position.  In this case, the search will have actually succeeded, but checking for a changed cursor position would indicate (falsely) that it hadn't.

Answer (score 2):

Vim has `search()` function. `:h search(` to read the function description.

If a match was found, the func will return the line number, otherwise return `0`. You can do your logic based on the return value of the function.

To check if some pattern in current line, you can use the `search()` function too, also you can `split()` the text of current line, to see if you got the result list with more than 2 elements.